# Collection choice set not available in Assignment element

Tags: visual-workflow, multi-select, screen-flow

I have a screen flow with a multi select for the user to select what records they want to update. I am trying to use the collection choice set in an assignment element to remove the first Id until the list is empty. However, it will not let me use a collection choice or record set. Are there any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. [Possibly useful](https://unofficialsf.com/multiselect-magic-manage-multiselect-picklists-with-flow/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to use a Loop to iterate over all the records, apply the Assignment to reach record in the loop, then do you update at the end.